# Not able to access images from upload folder - express - multer - react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer, mern

I am working on my first ever MERN stack web app. I finished development and trying to host in VPS.
Everything working fine. But, I am not able to view the uploaded images. I share you the few details about the project structure.

1. React app is build for production and kept in public folder.
2. Upload folder is created where user uploaded images are kept and its location is stored in DB. (ex: /uploads/user1/img1.jpg). Using Multer to handle image upload.

This is the folder structure of my Express server which also servers static files.

```
 -MAIN_EXPRESS_APP_FOLDER
    ------Routes 
    ------Public
    ------Uploads
    ------package.json
```

To make  public and upload static, following codes are added in Server.js file:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/public')));
app.get('/*',(req,res)=>{
  res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname='public/index.html'));
})
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'))
```

I am able to access my web app and also i can insert data in DB. Image upload is working as expected. But, Express not serving uploaded images.
What could be problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for static content you set the folder to be public now what i think is you should move your uploads folder inside public and try to access the images hope they will be served currently your application is not allowing to server data else then public directory hope it will help you

Comment: can i have 2 static folder?

Comment: the solution you mentioned works well. But, there is a problem. I have used Multer to upload files and multer returns this as image path  'public/uploads/user1/img1.jpg'  and i am storing it in DB. To access this image, you have to exclude 'public/' from URL. (www.mysite.com/uploads/user1/img1.jpg)

Comment: So if you want to remove public from start you can use substr() function let suppose var str = "public/uploads/user1/img1.jpg";          str.substr(7);      str will give you uploads/user1/img1.jpg    And also mark it as solved so it can help others in future

Comment: ya. I was thinking about the same now!  i already wasted 2 days to fix it.

Comment: Lol you should ask the community before any ways have fun coding

Comment: thought it would be simple issue. But end up spending hours and hours. happens every time !

Comment: lol it always happens when you got stuck you get stuck for weeks sometimes for stupid issues. Can you please mark it as solved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187622/discussion-between-mzparacha-and-darshn).